# RecyclerView breaks layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView list that displays some data in my DB.
How do I hide RecyclerView position it prints to a textView which I didn't bind to it and some textviews are not displayed in the screen

I'm trying to achieve this

[image]

Here's the broken layout

[image: link]

Here's my RecyclerView Adapter

```
public class LogsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LogsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<LogsModel> logList;
private Context mContext;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerV;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtDate;
    public TextView txtTimeIn;
    public TextView txtTimeOut;
    public TextView txtDivision;
    public TextView txtDesignation;
    public TextView txtActivities;
    public TextView txtDepartment;


    public View layout;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        layout = v;
        txtDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtTimeIn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeIn);
        txtTimeOut = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeOut);
        txtDivision = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDivision);
        txtDesignation = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDesignation);
        txtActivities = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtActivities);
        txtDepartment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtDepartment);

    }
}

public void add(int position, LogsModel logs) {
    logList.add(position, logs);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(int position, LogsModel logs) {
    logList.add(position, logs);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public LogsAdapter(List<LogsModel> taskSet, Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    logList = taskSet;
    mContext = context;
    mRecyclerV = recyclerView;
}

@Override
public LogsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final LogsModel logs = logList.get(position);

     holder.txtDate.setText(logs.getDate());
     holder.txtTimeIn.setText(logs.getTime_in());
     holder.txtTimeOut.setText(logs.getTime_out());
     holder.txtDivision.setText(logs.getDivision());
     holder.txtDesignation.setText(logs.getDesignation());
     holder.txtDepartment.setText(logs.getDepartment());
     holder.txtActivities.setText(logs.getLog_content());

    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Option");
            builder.setMessage("Update or delete user?");
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //go to update activity
```

//                        goToUpdateActivity(logs.getId());

```
                }
            });
            builder.setNeutralButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    JournalDB db = new JournalDB(mContext);
                    db.deleteTask(logs.getDate());
                    logList.remove(position);
                    mRecyclerV.removeViewAt(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, logList.size());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            builder.create().show();
        }


    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return logList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: looking at your layouts, the result is correct? You have 7 `TextView`s and 7 fields are displayed, with correct alignments?  You must be assigning the wrong text to the fields if they aren't in order.

Comment: Err, Date was replaced by the list position and Time In textView isn't displayed

Comment: Yes .. read my comment. Check your id assignment

Comment: Nothing wrong with my assignment even in the BindView

Comment: what happens when you log to console `logs.getDate()` before you assign to your `TextView`.  If it prints `11` then your `LogsModel` is incorrect, or how it is created from your DB entries, or even how data is inserted into the DB.

Comment: Oh I see thanks it prints 11